# Using a Makefile for Java

Tags: java, makefile, gnu-make, build-system

For college, I have to use Java. However, I do not want to use an IDE. I like vim.

So I'm trying to create a Makefile to build my java projects. My requirements are :

1. No hardcoding of classes. The Makefile shall find all `.java` files in the `src` directory and any subdirectories, and compile the resulting classes to the `classes` directory.
2. Multiple `mains` : Files containing `main` functions shall have an executable `.jar` file built with a corresponding `MANIFEST.MF`. Listing them explicitly is acceptable, although I'm pretty sure something could be done with `grep` here to find them automatically (but I suck at `grep`)
3. A source jar for the whole project shall be created, containing unaltered `.java` files and no `MANIFEST.MF` or other extraneous files.

My best attempt so far (currently broken) follows :

```
include gmsl

targets := Client Server

# Folders 

binDir  := ./bin
clsDir  := ./classes
srcDir  := ./src
testDir := ./test

# Flags

version := 11

# Files

mainSrc := $(targets:%=$(srcDir)/tp1/%.java)
src  := $(shell find $(srcDir) -name *\.java -type f)
cls  := $(src:%.java=%.class)

# Rules

# Base
all     : $(targets)
again   : clean all
classes : $(cls)

# For debug
info:
    $(info mainSrc : $(mainSrc))
    $(info srcJar  : $(srcJar))
    $(info exeJar  : $(exeJar))
    $(info src     : $(src))
    $(info cls     : $(cls))

# Executables
$(targets): $(cls)
    $(shell cd $(srcDir))
    $(eval mainCls := $(shell find . -name *$@\.java -type f) )
    $(info mainCls = $(mainCls))
    jar --verbose --create --file=$(call lc,$@)-exe.jar --main-class=tp1/$@ -C $(clsDir) .

# Source
$(srcJar) : $(cls)
    jar --verbose --create --file=$@ --no-manifest -C $(srcDir) .

# Classes
$(cls):
    javac --release $(version) --source-path $(srcDir) -d $(clsDir) $(mainSrc)

# Cleanup
clean:
    -rm $(targets)
    -cd $(clsDir) && rm -rf ./*
```

Comment: *I do not want to use an IDE* you can make your life hard

Comment: For java applications we typically use tools like maven or gradle to build jar's not makefiles

Comment: Basic assumption: compiling Foo.java produces Foo.class . This is not always true. And if `make` cannot distinguish source/product dependencies, its main point is gone. Don't use `make` to compile `java`.

Comment: @teapot418 doesn’t it ? I’ve never seen a case where that wasn’t true, although I’m not very experienced with Java 

Comment: @Jens I just don’t like digging through menus to do anything. Plus IntelliJ and Eclipse are very slow, even on empty projects, and Eclipse breaks when using `git` outside of its interface

Comment: maven and gradle are command line tools.

Comment: @ice-wind That is true that IDE's sometimes are slow. But you will see the advantages if you import classes with very long names. Also the auto completion will make your work so much faster, that you do not notice the overhead of the IDE

Comment: Put a `class Bar {}` into a Foo.java file and see what happens. Not that you would necessarily encounter exactly that in your sources, but the point is that `make` is not suitable for java. The specialized tools are much better at it.

Comment: @Jens Neovim has completion and auto-import

Comment: @teapot418 Isn't that just forbidden in Java ? I thought any file could only contain one top-level class of the same name. I'm going to try to make Gradle work, but I already hate how complicated the file-tree is.

Comment: Instead of replying every off-topic comments, why didn't you show what is wrong with your Makefile ? gnu-make is a general purpose utility, so it's ok with Java or anything else ; I don't see any JAVA_HOME, neither CLASS_PATH and all the stuff needed by java to work properly ; 1st, try to compile by hand something, then implement it with make. And plz provide your errors.

Comment: @ValeryS. Java doesn’t need a `JAVA_HOME` variable; that’s a tenacious myth. Further, for the process of compiling from scratch, you normally don’t need a `CLASS_PATH` variable either.

Comment: “*A source jar … shall be created, containing … no MANIFEST.MF or other extraneous files.*”—That’s what we call a zip file. But I don’t get how this makefile works. Where do the values for `$(version)`, `$(srcDir)`, `$(clsDir)`, `$(mainSrc)` etc. come from?

Comment: @Holger: you're right, look, I usualy have 2 or 3 different java flavors (version) on my system, without a JAVA_HOME properly set in my env for each app I use, I doubt  it could work. JAVA_HOME has something to to with end user application, not java itself, that's right. But I told him this because I don't know what will going on with its work, just in case. Thank you.

Comment: @ValeryS. My apologies about the Makefile, it is incomplete. I'm not even sure about the general structure yet, this is just how it was when I got fed up 

Comment: @ValeryS. I don't really know how java works, and what those environment variables are for. Our class instructs us to "just use Eclipse" and didn't explain any compiler flags. I've read some of the docs, I haven't seen mention of these variables yet.

Comment: @Holger Those variables are adapted from my usual file-tree for C projects. The "useless" `jar` is something the teachers require, for some reason they don't want a `zip` or `tar`

Comment: A jar file *is* a zip file with a manifest. So if you omit the manifest, you end up with a zip file (just having a different file name extension). You can create such a file with `zip` and just name it `whatever.jar` but, of course, the `jar` command with the `--no-manifest` option might work as well. It’s not helpful to us to know that these variables “are adapted from your usual file-tree for C projects”. That doesn’t tell us enough to spot potential errors. Besides that, when your current attempt does not exhibit the intended behavior, it’s helpful to describe what happens instead.

Comment: @ice-wind, it is not forbidden for a class to be defined in a Java source file whose name does not match.  That does cause potential problems, however, as the Java compiler will then not be able to find the source for such a class if it discovers a need to build it.  Also, there are nested classes and interfaces, which *can't* be defined in source files matching their (full) names, though the above problem does not apply to them.

Comment: @ice-wind, it is a pretty strong **convention**, however, that top-level classes and interfaces be defined in correspondingly-named source files, and if you stick to that then it would ease your use of a `make`-based build system.  `maven` would be more conventional, but I use `make` for Java without any particular problems in a mixed-language project where Java is not the primary language.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: It's OK to prefer non-IDE solution. However, limiting yourself to "make" as your ONLY build tool will mostly like lead to one of two outcome for any non-trivial project:

1. Inefficient build(s), where each build will (re-)compile/(re-)package much more than what's needed (one of Make strength is incremental building, based on timestamp), OR
2. Unreliable build, which will at time not rebuilt required targets because it will fail to understand dependencies.

What's the alternative ? use a tool that is "understand" Java, and has proper built in actions for building Java artifacts:

- Maven: if you want modern solution, OR
- Ant: if you want bare-bone, "manual gear" solution.

Technically, your can build a Makefile that will execute ant/build for you.

```
compile:
    mvn build

clean:
    mvn clean

...
```